# Click on a picturebox and go to website

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseclick-event

I have a pictureBoxes that are being created at run time and I would like to be able to click on that box and go to a webpage after the program completes.  How can I create a click event for something like this?

This is what I am thinking:

```
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
                    PB.Name = "PB" + i.ToString();
                    PB.Location = new Point(51 * i, 331);
                    PB.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                    PB.ImageLocation = Sub1;
                    Controls.Add(PB);

    PB.Click +=new EventHandler(PB_Click); 


    protected void PB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

{

MessageBox.Show("You clicked the mouse over the PictureBox"); 

}
```

Is this on the right track?

Comment: You're on the right track.  Look at using System.Diagnostics.Process to launch the URL.  if you just launch the URL the operating system should use the default browser for the machine. [This post might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209486/system-diagnostics-process-starthttp-google-com-crashes-ie)

Comment: Define what do you mean by "program completes"? Is it the application closes, just an other event or end of an action.
Generally, to open a website like @DavidStratton refered: PB.Click += (sender, args) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.webpage.com");

Comment: Duh.  Sorry, I didn't realize you were using a WebBrowser control - there was nothing about that in your question.  I'd have never suggested using System.Diagnostics.Process to launch the web page had I realized you were using a WebBrowser control.  That's an important detail to have in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]After fooling around a little I figured it out and thought I would post my solution, maybe someone else could benefit.  I decided to take the easy route and just open up the link using webrowser control on the form.

```
![private void FrmWeb_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();

            PB.ImageLocation =  "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000038434114/f676cbea6f8500c9c15529e1d5e548c1_reasonably_small.jpeg";
            PB.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            Controls.Add(PB);

            PB.Click +=new EventHandler(PB_Click); 


        }

        protected void PB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://twit.tv/");

        }][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want open Internet explorer and navigate to the desired address automatically, use this:

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com");
```